Nested ViewChilds in Angular component, unit testing
I have a parent component, where in my template i have button :
<button
        actions
        data-cy="appointment-creation-calendar"
        *ngIf="tabIndex === 1"
        [disabled]="!needsFormComponent || !needsFormComponent.needsFormComponent.isFormValid || !needsFormComponent.vehicleInfoComponent.group.valid"
        (click)="submitCustomerNeeds();"
    >
    </button>

and submitCustomerNeeds function :
submitCustomerNeeds(): void {
        console.log(this.needsFormComponent.needsFormComponent.isFormValid)
        console.log(this.needsFormComponent.vehicleInfoComponent)
        const operations = this.needsFormComponent.submit();
        this['toUnsubscribe'] = this.dealerResourcesService.getDealerResources(ResourceTypes.ccPool).subscribe(val => {
            this.ccResource = val.find(res => res.type === 'COURTESY_POOL');
        });
        this.ccPrice = operations.courtesyCar.price;
        this.operationArr = operations.operations;
        this['toUnsubscribe'] = this.operationsService.submitCustomerNeeds(operations, this.receptAndRest).subscribe(() => {
            if (!this.isSubmitCustomerNeedsButtonClicked) {
                this.tabIndex++;
                this.isSubmitCustomerNeedsButtonClicked = true;
            }
        });
    }

i want to test, that when i click two times on button, that tabindex is increased just one time so my test looks like this :
describe('AppointmentsCreationComponent', () => {
    let component: AppointmentsCreationComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppointmentsCreationComponent>;
    const date = {
        value: '',
        placeholder: '',
        type: ''
    };
    beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        GeneralModule.forRoot(),
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        NoopAnimationsModule
      ],
      providers: [
        AppointmentCreationVehicle,
        MatDialog,
        Dialog,
        TranslateStore,
        { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} },
          {provide: AppointmentCreationCustomer, useClass: FakeAppointmentCreationCustomer},
          {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: fakeActivatedRoute},
          {provide: UserService, useClass: FakeLocalUserService},
          {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: date},
          {provide: CustomerService, useValue: new FakeCustomerService()},
          {provide: AppointmentsRestService, useValue: fakeAppointmentsRestService},
          {provide: Data, useValue: fakeData},
          {provide: VehicleRestService, useValue: fakeVehicleRestService},
          {provide: MessageManagementService, useClass: FakeMessageManagementService},
          {provide: OTSRestService, useValue: fakeOtsRestService},
          {provide: InterventionListService, useClass: FakeInterventionListService},
          {provide: OperationsService, useClass: FakeOperationService},
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppointmentsCreationComponent,
        mockDirective({
            selector: '[ng2TelInput]',
            inputs: ['ng2TelInputOptions']
          }),
        mockDirective({
            selector: 'rds-service-advisor-customer-information',
            inputs: ['vehicle', 'customer'],
            outputs: ['state']
        }),
        mockDirective({
            selector: 'rds-service-advisor-customer-needs',
            inputs: ['customer', 'operations']
        }),
        mockDirective({
            selector: 'rds-service-advisor-summary',
            inputs: ['customer', 'appointment', 'ccPrice']
        }),
        mockDirective({
            selector: 'rds-service-advisor-dialog-new-value'
        }),
        mockDirective({
            selector: 'rds-service-advisor-confirmations',
            inputs: ['appointment', 'confirmationStatus', 'displayDmsError']
        }),
        mockDirective({
            selector: 'rds-service-advisor-customer-type',
            outputs: ['state']
        }),
        mockDirective({
            selector: 'rds-service-advisor-customer-professional',
            inputs: ['vehicle', 'customer'],
            outputs: ['state']
        }),
        mockDirective({
            selector: 'rds-service-advisor-customer-dialog'
        }),
        mockDirective({
            selector: 'rds-service-advisor-agenda',
            inputs: ['operationDuration', 'viewDate', 'receptAndRest', 'operationArr']
        }),
        mockDirective({
            selector: 'rds-service-advisor-calendar-header',
            inputs: ['view', 'excludeDays', 'dateFormat', 'viewDate', 'courtesyCarInvolved']
        }),
        mockDirective({
            selector: 'rds-service-advisor-confirm-appointment'
        }),
        mockDirective({
            selector: 'rds-service-advisor-basic-container-content',
            inputs: ['title', 'subtitle']
        }),
        mockDirective({
            selector: 'rds-service-advisor-basic-container',
            inputs: ['title', 'subtitle']
        })
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppointmentsCreationComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

it('should increment tab index just once when we double click customer needs button', () => {
        const needsFormComponentSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('CustomerNeedsComponent', ['submit']);
        needsFormComponentSpy.submit.and.returnValue({
            courtesyCar: {
                price: 10
            },
            operations: []
        });
        needsFormComponentSpy.vehicleInfoComponent = {
            group: {
                valid: true
            }
        }
        needsFormComponentSpy.needsFormComponent = {
            isFormValid: true
        }
       
        const operationService = TestBed.inject(OperationsService);
        spyOn(operationService, 'submitCustomerNeeds').and.returnValue(of([]));
        component.needsFormComponent = needsFormComponentSpy;  
        component.tabIndex = 1;

        fixture.detectChanges();

        const button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('[data-cy="appointment-creation-calendar"]'))

        button.nativeElement.click();
        button.nativeElement.click();

        expect(component.tabIndex).toBe(2);
    });

}

my parent Component has:
@ViewChild('customerNeeds', {static: false}) needsFormComponent: CustomerNeedsComponent;
and CustomerNeedsComponent(CHILD) has :
@ViewChild('needsFormComponent', { static: false }) needsFormComponent: NeedsFormComponent;
@ViewChild('vehicleInformation', { static: true }) vehicleInfoComponent: VehicleInformationComponent;

So my problem is that on fixture.detectChanges() i got error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isFormValid')
i thought with that createSpyObj and setting vehicleInfoComponent and needsFormComponent it will be there, but from some reason it is not. Interesting thing is that when i directly call submitCustomerNeeds in test and not fixture.detectChanes and trying to click i can see in console.log that i have objects there which are returning true. What i am doing wrong ?

Angular will set the NeedsFormComponent whatever you do. You are trying to manipulate Angular mechanisms. I feel like there is just no NeedsFormComponent  definition present in your test at all?
And the condition is wrong i believe as well, it should be something along the lines of:
!needsFormComponent?.needsFormComponent.isFormValid || !needsFormComponent?.vehicleInfoComponent.group.valid
Your condition will throw a undefined error if needsFormComponent is not defined.
